# How to show "Update to Attendee" popup in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, alert

In Outlook 2007, after I edit a meeting/an appointment, I usually get a popup as photo below. But, in OL2010, I cannot see it any more. I want to select the "Send updates to all attendees" option after editing and sending the meeting/appointment. Is there any configuation that I can be enable it?

[image]

Comment: When you edit a existing meeting, At the top left there is a send update option.

Answer (score 0):

See here for one official explanation there could be others.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2649499?wa=wsignin1.0

Possible workarounds for deletions only.

1 - Go offline first. The update will go into the Outbox. Delete the update from the Outbox. You then ask the people you deleted to remove the meeting from their calendars.

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/change-outlook-meetings-dont-send-updates/

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/582

2 - You can try unticking in the Scheduling Assistant rather than deleting names.

Possible workaround when adding.

I no longer have to use this, so I may not remember the steps correctly. Save without sending. Try to close then send the update.